# Counting connections of specific agent type

Tags: anylogic

I have the code (see below), which counts agents ("developers") in a specific state. This works just fine.

Now I do not want to count agents in a specific state, but agents of a specific type only. How can I alter the code (or write some new code) to achieve this?

Thank you very much!

```
return this.getConnections()
    .stream()
    .filter(Developer -> Developer.inState(WantA))
    .count();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check object type in Java by using the `instanceof`keyword.

```
return this.getConnections()
.stream()
.filter(obj -> obj instanceof ClassName)
.count();
```